# SSH Check Connection

Tags: powershell, ssh

I would like to check if machines have SSH installed.
So, I have this script:

I want the script to try to connect on machines and make a .txt 'log' like this:

```
10.10.10.1 - Connection refused (machines not have SSH or is down)
10.10.10.2 - Connection OK
...
```

```
$db = Get-Content -Path ".\hosts.txt"

    $User = "user"
    $Password = "pass"

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $db -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true
```

In hosts.txt I have hostip for machines
eg:

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.3
...
```

Comment: Did you try your script? Does it have problem?

Comment: I don't know , I think work's but I can not try because I don't know how to make a txt (logs) with results

Answer (score 0):

Any ideea ?

```
$LogFile = ".\LogMachines.txt"

function LogMessage
{
    param([string]$Message)
    
    ((Get-Date).ToString() + " - " + $Message) >> $LogFile;
}
 
$db = Get-Content -Path ".\hosts.txt"

    $User = "user"
    $Password = "pass"

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $db -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

LogMessage -Message "$db connected - OK";
LogMessage -Message "$db failed to connect - X";
```